# Tricky partial fraction question

Tags: soft-question, partial-fractions

Partial fraction$$\frac{1}{x(x^{50}+1)}$$

Here's what I did,

$$\frac{1}{x(x^{50}+1)}\equiv\frac{(x^{50}+1)-x^{50}}{x(x^{50}+1)}$$

$$\frac{1}{x(x^{50}+1)}\equiv\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x^{49}}{(x^{50}+1)}$$

Am I correct ?

Comment: Depends on what result you are trying to achieve. If you want the denominators to be irreducible, then no, this is not correct. $$x^{50}+1 = (x^2+1) (x^8-x^6+x^4-x^2+1) (x^{40}-x^{30}+x^{20}-x^{10}+1)$$

Comment: Here is the solution with denominators irreducible over the reals: $$\dfrac{1}{x (x^{50} + 1)} = \dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{x}{25 (x^2 + 1)} - \dfrac{4 x^7 - 3 x^5 + 2 x^3 - x}{25 (x^8 - x^6 + x^4 - x^2 + 1)} - \dfrac{4 x^{39} - 3 x^{29} + 2 x^{19} - x^9}{5 (x^{40} - x^{30} + x^{20} - x^{10} + 1)}$$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Is there a specific way to factorize such polynomials?

Comment: I think it’s possible to brute force by method of undetermined coefficients, although $\textbf{nobody}$ wants to do it. Maybe there’s a way to do it on wolfram alpha?

Comment: Look at Cyclotomic Polynomials. $x^{100}-1 = (x^{50}-1)(x^{50}+1)$ so its factorization will include the factorization you seek. $$x^{50}+1 = \dfrac{\Phi_1(x)\Phi_2(x)\Phi_4(x)\Phi_5(x)\Phi_{10}(x)\Phi_{20}(x)\Phi_{25}(x)\Phi_{50}(x)\Phi_{100}(x)}{\Phi_1(x)\Phi_2(x)\Phi_5(x)\Phi_{10}(x)\Phi_{25}(x)\Phi_{50}(x)} = \Phi_4(x)\Phi_{20}(x)\Phi_{100}(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the anwer is correct and ready to be integrated.
 $$\frac{1}{x(x^{50}+1)}\equiv\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x^{49}}{(x^{50}+1)}$$

Comment: Sir, thank you. Can you verify the factorization in the comments above? I think it is incorrect

Comment: It depends on what the purpose of the partial fraction is.